# Setting the ExpandBar Size correctly

Tags: java, swt, e4

I have an [ExpandBar](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FExpandBar.html) with a [Group](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FGroup.html) on it.

```
ExpandBar bar = new ExpandBar(this, SWT.V_SCROLL);
bar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
ExpandItem item1 = new ExpandItem(bar, SWT.NONE, 0);
item1.setText(CORRANSWER);
item1.setControl(correctAnswerGroup);
item1.setImage(image);
```

The Definition of the Correct Answer Group takes place before that:

```
private void initCorrectAnswerGroup() {
    Group correctAnswerGroup = new Group(bar, SWT.BORDER);
    correctAnswerGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
            true, 1, 1));
    correctAnswerGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    (new Label(correctAnswerGroup, SWT.NONE)).setText(LABEL_TASK_TXT);

    taskTxt = new StyledText(correctAnswerGroup, SWT.READ_ONLY
            | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    gdTaskTxt = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, false, false, 1, 1);
    gdTaskTxt.widthHint = 800;
    gdTaskTxt.heightHint = 200;
    taskTxt.setLayoutData(gdTaskTxt);

    chooseAnswerTypeComposite = new Composite(correctAnswerGroup, SWT.NONE);
    chooseAnswerTypeComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,
            SWT.NONE, true, false, 1, 1));
    chooseAnswerTypeComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Label answerTypeLabel = new Label(chooseAnswerTypeComposite, SWT.NONE);
    answerTypeLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.NONE, true,
            false, 1, 1));
    answerTypeLabel.setText(LABEL_ANSWER_TYPE);

    answerTypeCombo = new Combo(chooseAnswerTypeComposite, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    answerTypeCombo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.NONE, true,
            false, 1, 1));
    answerTypeCombo.setItems(new String[] { ANSWER_TYPE_STANDARD,
            ANSWER_TYPE_RULE });

    (new Label(correctAnswerGroup, SWT.NONE)).setText(LABEL_CORRECT_ANSWER);

    correctAnswerMsgTokenTextField = new TokenTextField(correctAnswerGroup,
            true, false, true, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    GridData gdETxtCorrAnsMsg = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
            false, 1, 1);
    gdETxtCorrAnsMsg.heightHint = 40;
    correctAnswerMsgTokenTextField.getText()
            .setLayoutData(gdETxtCorrAnsMsg);
}
```

However the size of the ExpandBar is not correct. It cuts of the widgets horizontally and vertically and displays no ScrollBars at all. 
It tried to play around with the setHeight method for the [ExpandItem](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FExpandItem.html) but what I´ve tried seems to work neither...
What do I have to do to make the ExpandBar stretch vertically to the whole size of the correctAnswerGroup and displays ScrollBars horizontally?